# Short program fragments, give an analysis of the running time using Big-Oh notation

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I'm having some trouble counting these operations in these short bits of code. Can someone explain counting operations in code. I understand big-oh just need some insight on how to count and explain in big-oh.

1. my counting is below

`sum = 0;                    --> one operation n
for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )     --> 1+n+1+n= 2n+2
      sum++;`                --> n

```
                                       total= 3n+2
```

2.

`sum = 0;
for( i = 0; i < n2; i++)
    for( j = 0; j <  i; j++)
          sum++;`

Comment: So, what have you done so far? It would be good you would add your own attempt to counting, and where you feel you get stuck. Then we can help you with that. As it is asked now, it looks too much like you are asking us to do your homework.

Comment: not asking for an answer just explain

Comment: Why do you think `sum = 0` represents *n* operations? Or what does the *n* mean that you put after that line?

Comment: meaning that sum=0 is one operation in the code. n is the measure of time i use to count my operations.

Comment: But *n* is input-dependent. How can the time for executing `sum = 0` be *n*, when *n* is the length of the input array? They have nothing in common.

Comment: You should look at the number of times the *inner* loop executes in total. You shouldn't count elementary operations because they all have different costs

Comment: Can you explain how to count the operations in the code fragment then, im lost.

Comment: So the line sum=0 is one operation, then if the for loop only runs once then it would be one operation its self.

Comment: The loop executes n times, not 1.

Comment: If you don't know how many times the loop runs then it will be n. Correct?

Comment: The code shows exactly how many times it will run: *n* is mentioned.